# Interpret Logarithmic Values like Mean and Std

Tags: logarithms, standard-deviation, means

let's say i have a series of data containing prices on the log scale. How would i interpret a arithmetic mean of 0.55 and a std of 0.69 (both metrics are computed with the log prices).

Is there an intuitive explanation in terms of percentage change or anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_i$ your observations. Then the (observed) arithmetic mean $\hat\mu_{\log}$ of the logarithm of those is
$$
\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n\log(x_i)}{n} = \frac{\log\left(\prod_{i = 1}^n x_i\right)}{n} = \log\left(\prod_{i = 1}^n x_i^{1/n}\right)
$$
which is the logarithm of the (observed) *geometric mean* of the original values (i.e. $\exp(\hat\mu_{\log})$ is the geometric mean of the $x_i$).

The (observed) standard deviation of these values is
$$
\hat\sigma_{\log} = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n(\log(x_i) - \hat\mu_{\log})^2}{n-1}}
$$
but the $^2$ makes it a bit more difficult to transform the way we transformed $\hat\mu_{\log}$ above. However, $\exp(\hat\sigma_{\log})$ does have an interpretation as a measure of deviation from the (geometric) mean, not in terms of difference but in terms of ratio.

When you have a lot of observations where exactly half of them are $-1$ and exactly half of them are $1$, then the arithmetic mean is $0$, and the standard deviation is a little larger than $1$ (it tends to $1$ as the number of observations grows), which is the observed deviation from the arithmetic mean in all cases.

In exactly the same way, for a long list of observations where exactly half are $\frac12$ and exactly half are $2$, the geometric mean $\exp(\hat\mu_{\log})$ is $1$, and the "geometric standard deviation", $\exp(\hat\sigma_{\log})$ is a little larger than $2$ (and tends to $2$ as the number of observations grows), since all the observations deviate from the geometric mean by a factor of $2$.

In your case, this means that you have observed a geometric mean of $\exp(0.55)\approx 1.73$, and a standard multiplicative deviation from that mean of $\exp(0.69)\approx 1.99$. So what would usually be an interval of "mean plus or minus a standard deviation" now becomes
$$
[1.73/1.99, 1.73\cdot1.99] = [0.87, 3.46]
$$

Comment: Is there a good word for $\exp(\sigma_{\log})$? Geometric standard deviation? Standard multiplicative deviation? And does it matter which base you use for your logarithms? (Some rudimentary test calculations seems to hint that it does not.)

Answer (score 0):

You can interpret a logarithmic scale as the "order of magnitude" of the data. Assuming decimal logarithms,

- magnitude $-2\leftrightarrow 0.01$,
- magnitude $-1\leftrightarrow 0.1$,
- magnitude $0\leftrightarrow 1$,
- magnitude $1\leftrightarrow 10$,
- magnitude $2\leftrightarrow 100$
- ...

and all intermediates.

So you are estimating the central trend and the dispersion of the orders of magnitude.

A grocer will have low mean and deviation. A car seller, high mean and low deviation. A general store, medium mean and high deviation.

Note that the given values are unrealistic.